# Use Newtonsoft.Json in isolated-process Azure Functions in .Net 6.0

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, json.net, azure-app-configuration

I currently use Azure App Configuration to store all the config data. When i read the data, i would like to use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of the default `System.Text.Json` to correctly transform my data to custom types.

Unfortunately, i cannot find a way to tell the `HostBuilder` in the `Program.cs` file to use `Newtonsoft.Json` instead of the `System.Text.Json`. All my converters are written using `Newtonsoft.Json` and i really would like to not migrate them all to `System.Text.Json`.

As an example:

```cs
public Enum SampleEnum 
{
  [Description("Sample")] SampleAbc
}

public class SampleConfig
{
  public SampleEnum ConfigEnumA {get; set;}
}

// configuration is the IConfiguration object from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

var sampleConfig = new SampleConfig()
configuration.GetSection("section").bind(sampleConfig);
```

The `Description` value `Sample` is what comes from Azure App Configuration as a string and ideally my current `Newtonsoft.Json` converters should transform it to `SampleAbc` enum value when binding the object `SampleConfig`. This allows me to be type safe in code.

This means that `ConfigEnumA` should have a value of `SampleEnum.SampleAbc` instead of `Sample`

I have already tried using but it did not work although i am working with HTTP Triggers and not a web application

```cs
var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder().ConfigureServices(services => 
{
  services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
  {
    options.SerializerSettings.Converters = <my-custom-converters>
  }
)
});
```

if there is no way to use `Newtonsoft.Json` in Azure Function apps that arent Mvc applications, then can someone help with achieving the same behaviour with `System.Text.Json`?

Thanks for the help.
Cheers.

Comment: do you need specific functionality from newtonsoft.json? otherwise i'd suggest just migrating to system.text.json anyway: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/migrate-from-newtonsoft?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: Its not about functionality, its about the effort to migrate everything from `Newtonsoft.Json` to `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: @vivek86 Did you find a solution for using Newtonsoft.Json in an isolated process?

Comment: @Chai unfortunately i couldnt find a way. So i decided to brute force it i.e. read the json string as a plain string and then use the conversion manually via newtonsoft by calling JsonConvert.Serialize<>(). 

i could not find a way to force Azure Function Apps to use Newtonsoft instead of System.Text.Json via DI so that serialization and deserialization could happen automatically.

Comment: The problem is the deserialization of  `dynamic` or `IDictionary<string, object?>`

Answer (score -2):

- AFAIK, `Services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonOptions(...)` is for *System.Text.Json* whereas `builder.services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>`  can be used for *Newtonsoft.json*.
- If you want to use *Newtonsoft*, add  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson`  as a dependency from NuGet which contains `AddNewtonsoftJson()`  extension.

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson --version 7.0.0
```

[image]

- Thanks to @[Nate1zn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18154499/nate1zn), I found how to use `Newtonsoft.Json` in Azure Function apps, you can add a startup to your function project as below:

```c
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(NewtonsoftjsonfunctionApp.functionsample))]
namespace NewtonsoftjsonfunctionApp
public class functionsample : FunctionsStartup
{
  public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.services.AddMvcCore().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => 
    {
      options.SerializerSettings.//json settings
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that already and unfortunately that did not work. Moreover I am running Azure Functions in an Isolated-Process and the startup is different to that of an In-Process Azure Function.